# la fecha de mi input date en javascript llega con un dia menos

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, javascript-objeto

Buenos días tengo una duda de como resolver este problema , tengo un input type="date" pero  al agregar una fecha ejemplo el 15 de junio , me manda la del 14 de junio

tengo este código si me pudieran ayudar u orientar

```js
const currentDate = () => {
     let date:any = new Date(); 
     let month:any = date.getMonth()+1; 
     let day:any = date.getDate() +1; 
     let year:any = date.getFullYear(); 
     if(day<10)
     day='0'+day; 
     if(month<10)
     month='0'+month;
      return date = document.getElementById('currentDate').value=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
 }
```

```html
<div class="form-group" style="padding-left:15px">
                         <Input
                          inputTwo={customInput}
                          validSucces={programming.date? 'is-valid' : 'is-valid'}
                          id="currentDate"
                          label="Fecha"
                          type="date"   
                          bind:value={programming.date}
                          on:input={e => (programming.date = e.target.value)}
                         />
                     </div>
```

Comment: no podrías solucionarlo sumando un día más?

Comment: lo hice hay let day:any = date.getDate() +1;  , tenia dudas ya que estoy empezando con js

Comment: Ese código sin e `+1` de `date.getDate()` me da el día actual. `getMonth()` retorna los meses desde 0 a 11, pero `.getDate()` no, retorna de 1 a 31. En la consola puedes poner `Date()` para ver que día y que time zone tienes.

Comment: ¿Siempre llega con un día menos o depende de la hora del día en que obtienes la fecha?

Comment: hola @Triby , si siempre llega un dia menos

Answer (score 1):

Cuando obtengas el date del input debes de agregar T00:00:00 al new Date(), para formatear bien la fecha.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo, la que tiene el T00:00:00, te lo pone bien, y cuando se lo quitas te sale con un día menos:

```
export default function Input() {
  const formatDate = (e: any) => {
    const date = e.target.value;
    
    const PrototypeDate = new Date(`${date}T00:00:00`); // Si
    // const PrototypeDate = new Date(`${date}`); // No

    const day = PrototypeDate.getDate();
    const month = PrototypeDate.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = PrototypeDate.getFullYear();
    const superResult = String(day) + "/" + String(month) + "/" + String(year);
    console.log("superResult: ", superResult)
  };

  return (
    <div className="">
      <input type="date" name="" id="" onChange={formatDate} />
    </div>
  );
}
```